# Ubuntu error on boot screen even after deleting partition

Tags: boot, grub2, 18.04, lenovo, bios

I don't know why the below error (image) is showing every time I boot my PC. I need to press ok to enter Ubuntu boot. I have deleted partition and recreated several times, installed different OS, still the error is not going.

[image]

Comment: It looks specific to your BIOS? It would be interesting to know the brand and model name of your computer.

Comment: @sourcejedi Its Lenovo G50-80